# Retrieve stored image from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to store and retrieve image by using Firebase. It is okay when storing an image, but I can't show it in an ImageView. It doesn't give an error so I can't understand where is the mistake.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnSelectImage;
private ImageView mImageView;

private StorageReference mStorage;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1 ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSelectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_image);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //Get instance
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    btnSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("CameraPhotos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                //Show image
                Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(downloadUri).into(mImageView);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Upload Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v("Test","image load");

            }
        });


    }
}
}
```

Also give permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here is my Firebase Storage Rules

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/fir-app-ce89f.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.yusuf.firebaseapp.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Image"
        android:id="@+id/btn_image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you see the "Upload Done" toast?

Comment: Yes, Toast and Log are both okey, also I can upload image succesfully

Comment: I copied your code and ran with Firebase 9.6.1 and Picasso 2.5.2.  The image uploaded and downloaded successfully.  Maybe the problem is the properties on your `ImageView`.  Can you post the XML for it?

Comment: I posted XML, I am not sure but maybe it is about firebase version, I use 9.4.0 ?

Comment: I changed intent and make ACTION_PICK then test upload and retrive, it works fine, I think problem is about Image capture

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at [FirebaseUI 0.6](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage), which includes a Glide plugin that makes downloading an image from Firebase Storage as simple as:

```
// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
StorageReference storageReference = ...;

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = ...;

// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: This code is not updating image if image is updated in firebase with same storage name and URL. do we have any mechanism to update image in imageview if image is updated in storage?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is easier if you use this way

```
StorageReference mImageRef = 
FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("image/test.jpg");
    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    mImageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new onSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

            imageView.setMinimumHeight(dm.heightPixels);
            imageView.setMinimumWidth(dm.widthPixels);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
```

Comment: I see Firebase UI use Glide. But in Android Studio, when i implement it, it make error. So i choose Bitmap to show image from Firebase's results (byte array).

Answer (score 0):

```
    private List<Upload> uploads;
    Upload upload = uploads.get(position);
    Glide.with(context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
```