# Retrieving image from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, imageview, firebase-storage

I know this is a discussed topic, but here I am, after all other solutions I've found did not solve my problem. I saved multiple images in Firebase Storage and now I want to get one of them and put it into an `ImageView` on an `AlertDialog` (or another Activity).

I've read about `Glide` solution, but it doesn't work for me. Gilde:

```
Glide.with(ViewScenesSG.this) //ViewScenesSG is the Activity
                .load(reference) //the storage reference
                .into(imageView); //my imageView
```

Dependencies for Glide (I've tried with multiple versions and 4.8.0 is the only one that doesn't give me Build error):

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
```

I've also read about the `.using(new FirebaseImageLoader())` method, I've implemented the [FirebaseImageLoader()](http://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/storage/images/FirebaseImageLoader.java), but the `using()` method is not found => build error. I believe it's been removed.

The second version I've tried is this one (found in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162491/10695253)):

```
final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
       reference.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE)
           .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                   Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                   DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
                   getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
                   
                   imageView.setMinimumHeight(dm.heightPixels);
                   imageView.setMinimumWidth(dm.widthPixels);
                   imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
               }
           }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
               Toast.makeText(ViewScenesSG.this, "Couldn't retrieve image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });
```

But every time it goes on the Failure listener. Therefore, my imageView always remains empty.

In my logcat I observed this error:

```
E/StorageException: Could not open resulting stream.
    java.io.IOException: Could not open resulting stream.
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.createDownloadStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:145)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:36)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:167)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:164)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.ensureStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:325)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:262)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:175)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
```

But the image is there, in the Storage, and the reference points directly to it:

```
storageRef = storage.getReference("photos").child(title); //for all images in the current folder named with the 'title' attribute
StorageReference reference = storageRef.child(imageName); //for the image I want to retrieve
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Using the suggestion in the coments, I tried with:

```
reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Glide.with(ViewScenesSG.this)
                        .load(uri.toString())
                        .into(imageView);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewScenesSG.this, "Retrieving image failed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

but this time I get the error:

```
E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:433)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:450)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:441)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:70)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:62)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:76)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: The new error message means that `reference` is not pointing to an existing image in Firebase Storage. You'll want to check how you initialize `reference` and ensure that the image it refers to exists.

Comment: The reference is pointing correctly, I checked through Logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following [solution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui) (as suggested in the comments before):

Using the **Firebase UI** plugin with Gilde, I added the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.0'
```

Now, having the `StorageReference reference` pointing to the image, and the `ImageView` in which the content must be uploaded, the following code retrieves the image and puts it in the `ImageView`:

```
Glide.with(ViewScenesSG.this)  //this is the current Activity
                .load(reference)
                .into(imageView);
```

To be mentioned that the ImageView must have the **dimensions** set to a specific value, not using `wrap_content` or `match_parent` (at least for height in my case), otherwise it will appear as a small icon. This can also depend on how the image was saved before in the Storage.

Hope this will help someone else as well!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going wrong in your second snippet, but in the first snippet you seem to be passing a `StorageReference` to Glide. Since Glide doesn't know anything about Firebase Storage, that won't work.

Instead, you should get a download URL from Firebase Storage, which is a regular HTTPS URL that provides public access to the data, and pass that to Glide to render in the view.

Something like:

```
reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'

        Glide.with(ViewScenesSG.this)
                .load(uri.toString())
                .into(imageView);
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, I see the difference, but it still gives me failure.

Comment: I've updated my question with the new error. It couldn't find the object.

Comment: The new error message means that `reference` is not pointing to an existing image in Firebase Storage. You'll want to check how you initialize `reference` and ensure that the image it refers to exists.

Comment: Glide can know something about Firebase Storage with a plugin from Firebase UI.  The plugin needs to be installed to work correctly. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui

Comment: That's a separate part of the issue Doug. I decided to pick one thread and follow that. I you want to follow another thread, that's fine too of course, but probably best to do so in another answer.